# Laravel first() vs take(1)->get()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel, and am kind of following a youtube tutorial where were building a blog. Anyway, I am trying to make a page which shows single blog post, and uses slug instead of id to show it. Anyway, this is my blog controller:

```
class BlogController extends Controller {

    public function getSingle($slug) {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->take(1)->get();
        return view('blog/single')->with('post', $post);
    }
}
```

But this way, It wont work.. On my blog/single view, i cant access $post->title for example. But, when I do it like this:

```
class BlogController extends Controller {

    public function getSingle($slug) {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('blog/single')->with('post', $post);
    }
}
```

.. it works fine. I have access to title, body and created/updated at times.

What is the reason first method wont work?

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's because `take(1)->get()` will return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections) with one element.

`first()` will return element itself.

Comment: So if I use get() method, I always get collection, and if I want to display it, I have to loop through it?

Comment: @miqro exactly.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin 
if I use `first()` it means I will get the first record which matches my `where condition`, correct?